# Unable to load page with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

On my codeigniter HMVC project. When I try to run my first isset statement in **modules foreach** section. If I uncomment the code below then, fire fox loads page error **The connection was reset**.

But if I comment out the code like below the page loads fine very strange.

```
//if (isset($part[0]) && $this->setting->get($part[0] . '_status')) {
//  $data['modules'][] = Modules::run('catalog/module/'.$part[0].'/index');
//}
```

For some reason does not like using `isset($part[0])`

**How code works**

- `$part[0]` it returns the module name example **category**
- `$part[1]` it returns the module number example 66 **category.66**
- `$this->setting->get($part[0] . '_status')` returns either 1 if
  **enabled** or 0 if **disabled**.

What could be the cause of page not loading when I uncomment the code above. Any suggestions

Controller

```
<?php

class Column_left extends MX_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('catalog/extension/model_extension_extension');
        $this->load->model('catalog/design/model_design_layout');

        $route = $this->uri->segment(1).'/'.$this->uri->segment(2);

        // $route outputs like pages/category

        $layout_id = 0;

        if (!$layout_id) {
            $layout_id = $this->model_design_layout->get_layout($route);
        }

        if (!$layout_id) {
            // Setting library autoloaded
            $layout_id = $this->setting->get('config_layout_id'); 
        }

        $data['modules'] = array();

        $modules = $this->model_design_layout->get_layout_modules($layout_id, 'column_left');

        foreach ($modules as $module) {
            $part = explode('.', $module['code']);

            echo $part[0];

            // Setting library autoloaded
            if (isset($part[0]) && $this->setting->get($part[0] . '_status')) {
                $data['modules'][] = Modules::run('catalog/module/'.$part[0].'/index');
            }

            if (isset($part[1])) {
                $setting_info = $this->model_extension_module->get_module($part[1]);

                if ($setting_info && $setting_info['status']) {
                    $data['modules'][] = Modules::run('catalog/module/'.$part[0].'/index', $setting_info);
                }
            }
        }

        // Setting library autoloaded
        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE .$this->setting->get('config_template'). '/template/common/column_left_view.php')) {
            $this->load->view('theme/'.$this->setting->get('config_template').'/template/common/column_left_view', $data);
        } else {
            $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/column_left_view', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<?php if ($modules) { ?>
<column id="column-left" class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
  <?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
  <?php echo $module; ?>
  <?php } ?>
</column>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: anything useful in error log?  Errors like that usually mean a browser timeout or too many redirects(which the browser usually detects, so more likely a timeout).

Comment: There are no errors showing just page times out when I commencement that code

Comment: just out of curiosity, can you run the if results without the if statement? In other words, which line is causing the timeout? That would help narrow it down some.

Comment: @SpYk3HH I have been working on it all afternoon and found the cause. It seem to be the fact the in a different controller folder had catalog/category and module/category. Which for some reason was causing that effect. So I renamed the controller in catalog folder to categories so like catalog/categories and refresh page and now working.

Comment: Past the answer then! :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working on it all after noon, was able to find the cause of the issue.

In my catalog modules folder I had 2 controllers named the same in different folders, catalog/category & module/category. Even though they were in different folders one was over riding other and causing page load error on fire fox.

How I solved problem. By renaming the controller in subfolder catalog to categories I refreshed page and then works.

I also cleaned up code here.

```
<?php

class Column_left extends MX_Controller {

public function index() {
    $this->load->model('catalog/design/model_design_layout');

    $route = $this->uri->segment(1).'/'.$this->uri->segment(2);

    $layout_id = 0;

    if (!$layout_id) {
        $layout_id = $this->model_design_layout->get_layout($route);    
    }

    if (!$layout_id) {
        $layout_id = $this->setting->get('config_layout_id'); 
    }

    $data['modules'] = array();

    $results = $this->model_design_layout->get_layout_modules($layout_id);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $part = explode('.', $result['code']);

        if (isset($part[0]) && $this->setting->get($part[0] . '_status')) {
            $data['modules'][] = Modules::run('catalog/module/'.$part[0].'/index');
        }

        if (isset($part[1])) {

           $this->load->model('catalog/extension/model_extension_module');

            $setting_info = $this->model_extension_module->get_module($part[1]);
            if ($setting_info && $setting_info['status']) {
                $data['modules'][] = Modules::run('catalog/module/'.$part[0].'/index', $setting_info);
            }
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/column_left_view', $data);
}
}
```